# Installing Nginx "Headers More" module with YUM

Tags: nginx

I would really like to avoid the custom patching/compiling stuff as upgrades are a nightmare. On Nginx, which I've installed using yum install nginx18, I'd also like to enable the popular module: https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/headers_more/

However, it's hard to find any instructions on how to enable the module in a yum-friendly way. Could someone please direct me to instructions, or mention the command? Thank you.

Comment: Very good question ! With Dedian Ubuntu you can apt-get install nginx-extras but I've got idea on how to do that with Centos.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to give a not-answer, but I don't think there is a yum-friendly way to install `headers_more` (but it would be great if I were wrong on this!), unless you want to go through the effort of creating the nginx+headers_more RPM yourself (and someone has worked on this apparently: https://github.com/feedforce/nginx-headers-more-rpm), but you need to maintain it then, and you would be repeating the steps of patching and upgrading anyway.

On the other hand, building nginx from source is incredibly easy, as is patching it, and can be easily automated from a script, too. Nginx even allows for [binary upgrading on the fly](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/), so you can upgrade without downtime. Checking configuration arguments is easy too, so you don't even need to keep track of them for the next upgrade, just use `nginx -V` to see them.

Comment: Building from source may be easy on a development machine, but it's not easy to do it from a base AMI on AWS with Chef or Puppet when the production system needs to start up quickly and is not allowed to contain gcc or make. Really kind of stinks this is not in epel or remi.

Comment: Thank you @suitablyawesome. That is a non-answer :) Sadly the truth is that CentOS land has no easy Yum way of doing this, the way Debian/Ubuntu communities have.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest webtatic-release rpm from
   http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/el7/x86_64/.
2. Install webtatic-release rpm:

   ```
   # rpm -Uvh webtatic-release*rpm
   ```
3. Install nginx1w rpm package:

   ```
   # yum --enablerepo=webtatic install nginx1w
   ```
4. Module Headers

   ```
   # yum --enablerepo=webtatic install nginx1w-module-headers-more
   ```

Answer (score 0):

try to convert the debian package with [alien](https://joeyh.name/code/alien/)